# Python mail: encoded attachments are truncated

Tags: python, base64, sendmail

I'm using the following function to send an email message with two attachments in my python script:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

...

def sendMail(sender_name, to, subject, text, files=None,server="localhost"):
      assert type(to)==list
      if files:
        assert type(files)==list
      print "Files: ",files
      fro = sender_name

      msg = MIMEMultipart()
      msg['From'] = fro
      msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
      msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
      msg['Subject'] = subject

      msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

      if files:
        for file in files:
# ************** File attaching - Start **************
                part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
                Encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
                msg.attach(part)
# ************** File attaching - End **************

      server.set_debuglevel(1)
      server.ehlo()
      server.starttls()
      server.ehlo()
      server.sendmail(fro, to, msg.as_string())
      server.quit()
```

I get the mail, and the attachments are there, but for some reason, they are truncated a bit. My guess is I'm missing something in the encoding process.

For example:

Attachment 1: Original file byte count is 1433902, while the new byte count is 1433600

Attachment 2: Original file byte count is 2384703, while the new byte count is 2383872

Any ideas?

Comment: You use `'rb'`. That is good. Did you have a version which didn't use that and are you under Windows? Are you sure that your obervation still is true?

Comment: I don't have another version. I'm on MacOSX. I actually just running the script again, using "r" as well, but the count is still smaller.

Comment: Seems to work ok for me. I observe that your output sizes are multiples of 8192; maybe there's some kind of buffering issue? Try reading each file into a variable first and print out its size.

Comment: Finally found what happened. See my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out I tried sending the files before the buffer of the writing process was fully flushed.

So, it was a synchronization issue and not an encoding issue.

Sorry about that, and thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Nice catch, I guess @Michael's answer was a useful clue.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but it's not much of an answer unless you explain _how_ you solved it.  I am running into the same problem, and since I would appear to be doing all this synchronously, it's hard to see how it's a timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be related to your current `base64.MAXBINSIZE`? `Encoders.encode_base64` uses `base64.encodestring` internally. The default value for `base64.MAXBINSIZE` is 57, can always try setting it larger: `base64.MAXBINSIZE = 65536`

Comment: Where is `base64.MAXBINSIZE`? Couldn't find it in `Encoders`.

Comment: Encoders imports base64, and in base64 MAXBINSIZE = (MAXLINESIZE//4)*3 and MAXLINESIZE = 76

Comment: OK, I added Encoders.base64.MAXBINSIZE = 65536, but for some reason it results in way smaller files (64K instead of 1400K). Why does this happen?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I finally found what happened. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already written--be sure to .close() the file and re-open()/.read() it for the payload.

My issues stemmed from timing and this solved the issue for me.